# Trying to make a function that finds the Fibonacci number of a user input number

Tags: c++, function, fibonacci

I am trying to make a program where the user enters a number, then that number is entered into a function and it outputs the element of the Fibonacci sequence that that number is.

It's giving me an error that says

> stack around the variable 'fib' was corrupted

I don't know if this is a logic error or a program error. Also I don't know if my logic for finding the Fibonacci number is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Fibonacci(int num)
{
    int fib[] = { 0 }, answer, i = 3;
    fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;
    fib[0] = 0;
    for (i = 3; i < num; i++)
    {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
    }

    answer = fib[num];
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    int user_number, i = 0;
    cin >> user_number;
    cout << Fibonacci(user_number) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression `int fib[] = {0}` either declares an array of 1 element or is undefined behavior.  The problem is that the compiler doesn't know how many elements to initialize.

Comment: What size do I make the array if I dont know what number the user is going   to input?

Comment: Added some punctuation and removed some blank lines from the code fragment so it takes less vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `fib` with only one element, so buffer overflow occurs, To fix it, you can use dynamic memory allocation. Define `fib` as `int*` (pointer to int) and allocate with `fib=malloc(sizeof(int)*num);`, and don't forget to release with `free(fib);`. Or, if your compiler supports C99, you can use a variable-length array.

And there's a better algorithm that doesn't need arrays. Because Fib(n) only depends on Fib(n-1) and Fib(n-2), you can use two variables to store Fib(n-1) and Fib(n-2), without storing previous elements.

Comment: I tried int 'int fib[99999];' but it still gave me the error. How can I declare the number of elements in the set if I dont know how many numbers the user is going to want?

Answer (score 0):

1The stack corruption is most likely because of your array

```
int fib[] = { 0 }
```

You've declared an int array of size 1, then immediately after access data beyond the bounds of the array

```
fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;
```

---

As for the Fibonacci sequence, it is particularly easy to implement with recursion;

```
int Fib(int var)
{
  if (var < 1)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (var == 1 || var == 2)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return Fib(var-2)+Fib(var-1);
  }
```

Comment: It can be implemented with recursion, but it would be slow with a large `var`.

Comment: If your concern is speed you could implement with templates, then the work is done at compile time leaving just a static look up at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You have a principal problem, doing the loop until num - 1, you have to change it to:

```
                            for (i = 3; i <= num; i++)
                            {
                                fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
                            }
```

to do the complete secuence. and maybe you have a problem initializing your array, you are not bound to do it, just declare it:

```
                            int fib [num]; //the size is because num gonna be the last element of your array.
```